# Post object of array to api in ReactJs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

When I have post the Array of object via API to the server than data is not pass properly to the api.
My object have 2 property one is GUID type and one is string type, at the server side my each object return as null data.

[image]

In console posted data is this

[image]

posted Params data is this

[image]

I am beginner in the reactJs so can any one help me how I can save object or array or any array via API

Comment: `title` vs `Title`, `categoryId` vs `CategoryId`

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu I have tried this way too, but not got success, if you see I get the no of object in list on server but they are not converted properly.

Comment: Please share the code you use to make the API call. Note that React has nothing to do with network calls.

Comment: I am not created any API just calling he controller method, this issue coming only when pass array or object of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have make changes in my post method and now my Ajax post method this.

```
export function postJson(url, data, success, error = nothing) {
  const settings = {
      url,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      type:     'POST',
      async:    true,
      success:  onSuccess(success, error),
      error,
  }
  if (data) {
      settings.data = JSON.stringify(data)
  }

  $.ajax(settings)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `JSON.stringify(dataToPost)` in the reactjs to convert the data to string before posting to server. I hope the server is RESTful API

Comment: I have tried the same but did not work, I did not have any REST API , I am just calling a method of my controller.